# Merging two data environments and do.call()

Tags: r

consider the following code

```
require(quantmod)

list.X <- c('ANFCI',  'NFCI', 'STLFSI', 'WAAA', 'WBAA', 'WCOILWTICO','WFII10', 
            'WGS10YR', 'WGS1YR', 'WGS3YR', 'WGS5YR', 'WSWP10', 'WTB3MS')
data.X <- new.env()
getSymbols(list.X, src = 'FRED', from = '1950-01-01', env = data.X)
```

Now I put those time series in `data.X` environment; let I need to put in `data.X` another time series:

```
getSymbols('SPY', from = '1950-01-01', env = data.X)
```

By default, this is downloaded from Yahoo. With the last command, did I put it into `data.X` as I need?

Then let I want to merge them. I believed that something like

```
X <- do.call(merge, as.list(c(list.X, 'SPY')), envir = data.X)
```

could work, but that command dosen't work.

Coudl you suggest me something working?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by merge them? You might want to look at `eapply`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
mmerge <- function(.list, all=FALSE, env=.GlobalEnv) {
  .list <- lapply(.list, get, env)
  Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=all), .list)
}

head(mmerge(list.X, env=data.X))
head(mmerge(as.list(c(list.X, 'SPY')), env=data.X))
```

with a nod to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list-simultaneously)